# Angular search optimizing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular application that is ment to search through 1000+ objects. is tearing on the ui and the application seems slow.

The objects im searching through looks like this:

[image]

The current array im searching through is 799 long.

My search method up till now has been  an input field with the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Søg" ng-model="search.$">
```

As you might have guessed the problem is that im searching in all of the text.

So i attempted to change this to only search in  the `question` field:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Søg" ng-model="search.question">
```

However this did not help much. The UI is still "laggy" when i attempt to write in the search field.

So my question is how do i optimize this search and avoid a laggy ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't write what actually happens when you enter something into the input field. Anyway, instead of searching while the user is typing you can search after she has stopped typing, using `ngModelOptions`:

```
<input ng-model-options="{ debounce: 200 }" ng-model="search.question">
```

This starts the search 200ms after the user has stopped typing.